# Could oom, oom-killer and outofmemoryerror be merged to oom?

Tags: support, tags

Could [oom](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/oom), [oom-killer](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/oom-killer) and [outofmemoryerror](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/outofmemoryerror) be merged to [oom](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/oom)?

Comment: outofmemoeyerror isn't Linux specific.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think [oom](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/oom) and [oom-killer](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/oom-killer) should be synonyms. The first one describes a specific situation and the second one a mechanism to handle said situation. They are of course closely related, but not the same.

[outofmemory](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/outofmemory) doesn't exist/isn't used .

Comment: Sorry. I meant outofmemoryerror

Comment: OutOfMemoryError is probably [Java exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html).  Thus it is completely different beast from kernel states and can't be merged too.